# theme font doesn't apply to paragraph

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

Okay, so I am just a beginner in HTML and CSS. I tried to apply wordpress themes font to everything else on the site. The font is "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif; . I even created a custom menu which works perfectly with this font, but when I try to apply it to paragraphs, like product descriptions, it just doesn't work. I tried to edit the style.css file with 

`* {
font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
}`

or

```
body {font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;}
```

Can some one please tell me maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but did you import the font into your website? You could include the font from Google its library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [integrated properly the Google Font](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#specifying_script_subsets) try with `!important`:

```
* {font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif !important;}
```

or

```
body {font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif !important;}
```

The CSS assigns a weight to each rule depending on the specificity of its selector and its position in the source. This determines which style is applied to an HTML element.

If 2 rules conflict on a single element then the following principles will be applied:

- **Origin of rules** - If a rule between an author and a user stylesheet conflicts, the user's rules will win over the author's rules.
- **Specificity** - When 2 or more declarations that apply to the same element set the same property and have the same importance and origin, the declaration with the most specific selector will be applied.
- **Source order** - When 2 rules have the same weight, the last rule declared in the stylesheet will be applied.

There might be times when it would be useful to change the order of sequence. It's possible to **break that cascading chain** by using the **!important** CSS declaration. When the !important declaration is used on a property/value, that value becomes the most important for that property and **overrides** any other.

Source: https://www.webcredible.com/blog/importance-important-css-declaration/

Answer (score 0):

There is alright with syntax,The font that you choose maybe does not  exist, so you must try another font-family or visit google fonts and pick your font-family

Answer (score 0):

Append `!important`

```
body {font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif !important;}
```